# How to get TAPI to work in Vista with C#?

Tags: c#, windows-vista, tapi

How do I get TAPI to work on Vista?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sax CommStudio](http://www.commstudio.com/commstudio/modems) supports TAPI. It's not free, but will save a mountain of time.

There are also some sample projects floating around out there, including [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/devangpro.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

If you're using C#, using TAPI directly probably won't work.  See this [KnowledgeBase article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841712) for details.  Bascially the managed wrapper that Visual Studio creates for the TAPI 3.x COM interface doesn't work.  You can use unmanaged code (C++, VB6) to work with TAPI 3.x, or you can use one of the TAPI OCX (a.k.a ActiveX) controls to access TAPI from .Net.  Googling for 'TAPI OCX' will get you a page full of free and shareware TAPI controls that you can check out.