# Create an application using TAPI on windows 7 - where to start

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-7, telephony, tapi

does it working with it and which is the good start for TAPI...

i want to create an application which automatically answer/record incoming call and also call to someone recorded message.

want this in .net (asp.net or c# desktop no problem).

Comment: I'm using TAPI with Windows 7 and it's working fine. You might want to check out my answer to following question, regarding TAPI wrappers for .NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333319/net-tapi-interface/2334053#2334053

Answer (score 3):

It seems unlikely that Microsoft would have removed TAPI from Windows 7 so ultimately this will depend on the telephone system and drivers you are using. Avaya and Cisco usually provide good drivers. We have an Avaya phone system in work and a few people using Windows 7 with no problems AFAIK.

There is little support for using TAPI from managed code, but it is possible using wrappers or 3rd party components (see [Microsoft Knowledgebase article 841712](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841712)).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803015/how-to-get-tapi-to-work-in-vista-with-c) might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to work with TAPI, C# and 64bit Windows 7, too. I wrote a very small program which uses ([the ITAPI assembly from codeplex](http://itapi3.codeplex.com/)).

`theTextBox.Clear();

foreach (TAddress addr in tapi.Addresses){

theTextBox.Text += addr.AddressName + "\n";

}

theTextBox.Refresh();`

tapi is a TTapi object and is initialized in the Form's constructor.

The resulting list seems to be some default list which painfully lacks the LAN TAPI Service Provider I installed. I currently have low hopes that there is a well working wrapper for this.