# .NET TAPI Interface

Tags: .net, tapi

I’ve been asked to write some .NET code that integrates with a phone system using a TAPI API. I read that there is no .NET interface for this API ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841712). Is there good third party .NET interface for TAPI? Or can anyone point me in the right direction to get started?

Answer (score 8):

There is no working out-of-the-box interface from .NET for TAPI, and COM-Interop is not reliably working, that's right. But, there is a C++/CLI TAPI 3.1 wrapper for .NET 2.0 freely available from [Julmar](http://www.julmar.com/tapi/) (you just have to give credit) . Look there for ITAPI3. They include also some basic inbound/outbound call samples.

If you want to code against TAPI 2.x, then you could use the wrapper provided by Helen Warn and Agile-Soft which can be downloaded from Andreas Marschall's TAPI FAQ site. See this [newsgroup post](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.tapi/browse_thread/thread/be7f7d15f9478200) for the [link](http://www.I-B-A-M.de/AgileSoftwareInc/HelenWarnCsharpTapi2LibraryWrapper_Version_1_2_0_1.zip). It's also free for use (check the readme).

Answer (score 0):

Even C4F's tapi is cool to work. this [Tapi](http://c4fdevkit.codeplex.com/) is a good dll to work with .NET .  It also has some sample which you can try out.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, TeleTools has an excellent set of controls for any TAPI or SIP device and Visual Studio. The new version has a a new set of controls that is even easier to use for 90% of the applications out there so you don't have to learn a large set of events, methods and properties. A wrapper around TAPI is still way too much work than a good set of controls that do most of the work for you. Most applications like caller id and dialing are only a few lines of code. In addition, ExceleTel is the only telephony company with TeleScope, which is a prototyping, logging, learning tool that is unique. The logging will save you a lot of time and let you see exactly what your device/phone line/application is doing.

ExceleTel has been around for over a decade working with TAPI and consulting with the manufacturers who write the TAPI drivers (TSPs) to make their devices work. You can find a lot of information on the website, www.exceletel.com, and you can get more info on the tapi for win32 newsgroup where we all share information.

FULL DISCLOSURE: Fred works for Teletools (http://www.microsoftfaqs.com/msg/14811958.aspx)